# Non-reactive Spring web with kotlin functional router

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-dsl

Can I use new Kotlin DSL for setting up routing, for example as in :

```
router {
    ("/blog" and accept(TEXT_HTML)).nest {
        GET("/", fooHandler::findAllView)
        GET("/{slug}", fooHandler::findOneView)
    }
    ("/api/blog" and accept(APPLICATION_JSON)).nest {
        GET("/", barHandler::findAll)
        GET("/{id}", barHandler::findOne)
    }
}
```

with non-reactive web part? In the sense that underlying database will be Postgres and non Reactive servlet based application server so I do not want/need to use Flux or Mono for return types of `barHandler` or repository functions. But I do like new router DSL when used with Kotlin and it is more powerful than annotation based `@RequestMapping` and easier to get a grasp of all the app routes.

Comment: what do you mean by "non-reactive web part" a Spring MVC application?

Comment: @BrianClozel Think of like using Spring-WebMVC but with Kotlin functional DSL for writing up the router and not using annotations for it. All examples say that you can use DSL and annotations for WebFlux, but never mention if it is the same for WebMVC or we are stuck with just annotations there?

Comment: @SašaŠijak you could use a non-spring web framework (while keeping all the spring parts that you want).  Examples of such frameworks are: Ktor, Javalin, and (my favorite, despite no websockets) http4k

Comment: @pabl0rg I know that, but my question is if I could use this particular part of WebFlux package with WebMVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DSL in your example is part of **Spring WebFlux**, which is the "reactive" thing you speak of. In this official blog [post](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/04/introducing-kotlin-support-in-spring-framework-5-0), the functionality is being introduced as "Spring **WebFlux** functional *DSL*".

The DSL entry point `router` is defined in the package `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server` which also verifies what I said earlier. You can have a look at it on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/RouterFunctions.java).

What you can use with traditional Web MVC though: The **Functional bean declaration DSL** that is used to define your application beans in a way that looks as follows:

```
beans {
    bean<Foo>()
    bean { Bar(ref()) }
}
```

Comment: I confirm it is not possible to use the Kotlin router DSL with Spring MVC which only supports the annotation-based programming model, not the functional one.